# Query not passing with View in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have the foloowing controller (supernavigationloggedin):

```
<?php

class Supernavigationloggedin extends CI_Controller {  
    function index(){
        #get current session id
            $currentSessionID = $this->session->userdata('session_id'); 
        #get all the account row for the given sessionID
            $data['info'] = $this->db->get_where('Client', array('session_id'=>$currentSessionID))->row(); 
        #views
            $this->load->view('supernavigationloggedin',$data);
    } 
}


?>
```

and the following view named(supernavigationloggedin):

```
<div id="superNavigation">
    <h5><strong>Welcome</strong>, <?php $info->fname; ?>&nbsp;<a href="#">Account Settings</a></h5>
    <div class="clearL"> </div>
</div
```

>

It keeps throwing an error on line:`<h5><strong>Welcome</strong>, <?php echo $info['fname']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="#">Account` that Message:  >>>  `Trying to get property of non-object`

I've tried : `<?php echo $info['fname']; ?>   <?php echo $info->fname; ?>`  but neither seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `$info`  is empty and no database request are made. You have to do this this way if you want your query to return an object:

```
$data['info'] = $this->db->get_where('Client', array('session_id'=>$currentSessionID))->row();
```

Or this way, if you prefer to get it into an array:

```
$data['info'] = $this->db->get_where('Client', array('session_id'=>$currentSessionID))->row_array();
```

This way it should work. `row()` or `row_array()` is necessary to execute your query.

Comment: Thanks for the post. So, to output in my view I do the <?php $info['fname']; ?>    is that right ?

Comment: If you use the first query of my answer, you use `$info->fname`, if you use the seconth, you use `$info['fname']`. I suggest you to use `print_r($info)` in your view to see what it contains.

Comment: But does this $info->fname require echo $info->fname ?

Comment: `$info->fname` is a variable, if you want to show it, yes use `echo`. Otherwise, use it as any variable.

Comment: Please see my updated code above ... its throwing a error of Trying to get property of non-object on that same var

Comment: Maybe something is wrong in your query and it returns nothing, please check in your MySQL table if such row exists and if your column has fname set.

Comment: I've checked fname exists and there is definitely a session in the table.

Comment: I also tried the print_r() as you mentioned above and just get an error: Undefined variable: info

Comment: Well the problem is that your query doesn't find anything, so $info is empty and gets destroyed before showing the view by the framework, cause it's empty. It's hard for me to help you more, it's the most precise I can be without having the whole code and database in front of me. At least you know where is the error, keep digging in this way. :)